# Loading external properties file angular 2+

Tags: angular, configuration

I was wondering if there was any way in Angular 2+  that I could have my api url's in some external config.json file and load them prior to build. I ask this because in my current situation I am just defining them as variables in my service and if I want to make changes to the URL's I must manually change the code and rebuild. With this config file I was thinking of defining them there so that if I change the config properties, I would not have to rebuild the code each time I do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new angular-cli have the concept of different environments like development (dev) and production (prod).

When creating a new application with the cli ng my-app and /environments folder is a part of the scaffold which contains the environment files.

```
├── environment.ts
├── environment.prod.ts
```

When the application is built (ng build) or served (ng serve), the environment.{env}.ts file from /environments is pulled and replaces the file within /src/app. By default this is dev.

In order to grab the production version, set the environment to production using the following:

```
#build
$ ng build --environment=production
#shorthand
$ ng b -prod

#serve
$ ng serve --environment=production
#shorthand
$ ng s -prod
```

SAMPLE ENV FILE

```
export const environment = {  
  production: false,
  envName: 'qa'
};
```

Read more about ng build command **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)**

EXAMPLE

```
export const environment = {  
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://example.com/api'
};
```

**app.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { environment } from './environment';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'myapp-app',
  templateUrl: 'myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['myapp.component.css']
})
export class MyappAppComponent {  
  title = 'myapp works!';
  environmentName = environment.apiUrl;
}
```

**template**

```
<h1>  
  {{title}}
</h1>

<h2>  
  {{environmentName}}
</h2>
```

Comment: thanks, so I looked into the eviorments.ts files including prod, and was wondering is it in these enviorment.ts file where I would store the variables that would hold my api url"s? Also how would I link these eviorment variables to my service? Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can store your api url in environment file and pass the environment name during ng build

Comment: see the sample environment variable

Comment: @user3786798 : I have updated my answer according  to your need

Comment: Where do you put various access keys and stuff you don't want in the codebase?